# I am getting this error Forbidden (csrf token missing or incorrect.)

Tags: python, django

I am fairly new to python/django. But my code has been running perfectly fine. And now I am suddenly getting this error. My code is about file upload.

I have added {% csrf_token %} in the view.
 The "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware" is in the settings file.
 And I am returning the response with the render () function.

Is there anything that I need to check on? I have been running/testing this code for a week or so and now suddenly this error is popping up. I am not sure how to debug it.

Thanks in advance,
Vrunda

Comment: The token should be in your template, not your view =) Can you share some code please?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes the token is in the template.

Comment: my html code is  {% csrf_token %} 
<input type="file" id="file1" name="file1" multiple="multiple" onchange="check(event)" webkitdirectory> and part of code in view is class browse(UpdateView):    
    def post(self,request,**kwargs):        
        fileList=[]
        fileList = request.FILES.getlist('file1')  Sorry I am not able to enter/edit here properly.

Comment: Is the token inside a form? (And if you have a look when you edit your question you should see some formatting tips =) )

Comment: The_Cthulhu_Kid Thanks, Yes, it is inside form.

Answer (score 0):

Normally '403 Forbidden' errors occur for two main reasons:

1. In case of a Cross Site Request Forgery (which is probably not your case)
2. Programming error, CSRF token is not included with a POST form

Here is the [Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#rejected-requests)

Also, as you asked for possible approaches, see this duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31618511/7692463

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Paul Floyd. The error is resolved. I removed the 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'  in settings.py and was trying to work around using cookies. But I couldn't figure that out so I put  the line back again. And it's working again!  Thanks everyone for the help though